# Can I use AWS own ELB certificate for HTTPS/SSL connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate, aws-elb

I know that you can add your own certificate to the domain and point that domain to the AWS Elastic Load Balancer. In my case I don't have domain, but would like still use secure HTTPS/SSL connection when talking client <-> backend. Is it possible to enable HTTPS connection directly to ELB, i.e instead of using `http://some-random-url-here.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com` I would like to use `https://some-random-url-here.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com`

That would mean, that AWS would need to provide the cert for the `*.elb.amazonaws.com` domain. I remember at least long time ago this was possible, but maybe my memory does not serve me right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Memory does not serve you right.  This is not possible now and would not have been possible in the past.  ELBs don't have, and it is not possible to obtain, a certificate like this (including from Amazon Certificate Manager).

In fact, 3rd party providers like Let's Encrypt also have protections to prevent you from obtaining certificates like this, since `amazonaws.com` is not your domain.

You will need a domain that you control.

Comment: This is unfortunate but exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot Thank you for the direct answer. I've been researching about how to do this for a day now. I was not expecting to get a certificate but - like in amplifyapp.com that gives you free https - I thought that amazonaws.com can do that too.

Comment: azure can do that, they provide free https for all websites by default. You can add custom domain and your ssl to that if you want. At this point i dont like aws.